# Geographical redundency for database: What are the options?

Tags: database, distributed, distributed-computing, redundancy, distributed-system

We need to provide Geographical Redundancy in our project, it has massive DB (2-20 TB depending on specific customer's requirement). We have continuous in-flow of data from network (e.g. 1-20 GB per hour).

Currently we have Oracle (no RAC) with J2EE AppServer on a RHEL (Linux) cluster and SAN disks for storage, in short one DB, multiple AppServs.

What we need is Geographical Redundancy. Requirement can be summarized as, as long as things are fine 2 separate installations of our product serve 2 distinct networks (each serving one). When one of them goes down other one should serve both.

Additional notes:

- We need a relational DB with SQL support, as Warehousing is one of the basic needs.
- Prefer not to use hosted/cloud services like: http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/ as our customers can be extremely finicky abt security/privacy (even if the hosted/cloud services provide those).

Discounting the application logic what are the options for just replicating my data? STFW came up with only following results (as I'm no DBA expert, my interpretations might be wrong):

- Surprisingly I could not find a product from Oracle for Geographical Redundancy. Oracle RAC is for a local cluster (more for horizontal scalability than redundancy).
- MySQL [seems to support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ha-overview.html) only active-standby, when distributed. I need active-active.
- [Guident](http://www.guident.com/services/systems-engineering/high-availability/geographic-redundancy/) seems to be providing a service based on some Oracle products, but no product.

Thanks -- Kashyap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that [MySQL cluster](http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/) should work for you.
Other multi-master solutions could be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-master_replication).

Comment: didn't get everything I wanted but you're the only person to answer so... Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

While considering a geo-distributed database preferably with replication then we have to consider the trade-offs between preferring A (availability) or C (consistency) (in presence of WAN partition) else L (Latency) or C (consistency) (with no WAN partitioning).

Now, if your application can tolerate moderate latency having strong WAN backbone you should go for consistency (which is a dbms designed for) otherwise if the app can survive occasional staleness and periodical dis-connectivity in the WAN go for availability.

Then comes the challenge how to ensure consistency, availability and latency requirements for your app. What I have understood consistency in a replicated dbms comes through synchronous communication where providing availability mostly decrease consistency property (what the NoSQL systems offer now). However, ensuring latency requirement for such kind of dbms is still a open question to both database and system researchers (I guess!!).

Read more at http://danweinreb.org/blog/improving-the-pacelc-taxonomy

What I most liked to see these kinds of questions coming up in front of the whole community. These are real requirements and we are still in lack of proper solutions for them. Moving to a new  or open architecture from a system like Oracle is not a easy decision to make. It seems giants like Google is still searching for the correct answer. See http://research.google.com/archive/spanner.html

Comment: Thanks for taking time. Useful hints, but as you said a bit theoretical. I did study the basics of BASE and ACID (have been working with distributed systems for last 8-10 years) etc but well bottom line is you have to come up with the actual solution, theory only helps. Unlike local distribution (where there are out of box options like RAC) geographical distribution doesn't seem to have generic solutions available. Didn't know abt spanner though, sounds like an interesting option, except for my relational/warehousing requirements.